# Exposed filters in blocks on Drupal 7 view

Tags: drupal, view, block

I just had a question regarding how to manipulate a Drupal 7 view where I have 3 blocks created (which were then added on a panel) in order for a page to be organized based on three criteria. I want to allow the user to sort the content on each BLOCK based on an exposed drop-down widget but for some reason the exposed widgets don't show up in each tab when I have them exposed.

Can I not expose sorting criteria or filters in blocks?

Could anyone please help? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your structure here. So you've got 3 blocks, and you want to have an exposed filter on each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say.  If you are using it with Content Panes, I think I have the answer.

I think in your Views > "Allow settings" you accidently have "Use exposed widgets form as pane configuration" checked.  If that is checked it would hide the exposed Filters.  If you uncheck that you will see the Filters exposed in your blocks.

[image]